# Cordova android disable softkeyboard

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard

I'm building an android App using Cordova. This App will be use on a rugged scanner which get a physical numeric keyboard. My problem is, when i trigger the focus, the softkeyboard is triggered.

For now, I was trying to make a plugin to enable/disable the softkeyboard:

```
/**
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class KeyboardPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

  private View mView;
  private Context mCordova;
  private Boolean status;

  @Override
  public void initialize (CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    mView = webView.getView();
    mCordova = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)mCordova.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE    );
    if (action.equals("enable")) {
      status = true;
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mView.getWindowToken(),  InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    } else if (action.equals("disable")){
      status = false;
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Has anybody already doing that? There is some thread about it but they all are really old with old version of android and cordova.

There is no error it's simply doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a plugin that implements the same functionality. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard/blob/master/src/android/Keyboard.java#L18).

```
Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

View view;
try {
    view = (View)webView.getClass().getMethod("getView").invoke(webView);
}
catch (Exception e){
    view = (View)webView;
}

if("hide".equals(action)){
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    callbackContext.success();
    return true;
}
callbackContext.error(action + " is not a supported action");
return false;
```

The only major differences I see are two ways two get the view and having the view as a local instead of instance variable. Does using this code work for you?